# Artifact not being published to Bintray

Tags: travis-ci, bintray

Below project has  pom.xml ,travis.yml and settings.xml

[github-link](https://github.com/DhyansProjects/kafka-elasticsearch-standalone-consumer)

for some reason my artifact is not being published to bintray .

below are logs from travis ..

https://travis-ci.org/DhyansProjects/kafka-elasticsearch-standalone-consumer

```
0.00s$ echo TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST = "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" && echo TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION = “${TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION}” && echo TRAVIS_TAG = "${TRAVIS_TAG}"
TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST = false
TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION = “oraclejdk8”
TRAVIS_TAG = 
after_success.3

0.00s$ test "${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST}" == "false" && test “${TRAVIS_JDK_VERSION}” == “oraclejdk8″ &&  mvn deploy --settings settings.xml
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't  need to use Maven to publish to Bintray from Travis. You can use the [Bintray provider](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/bintray/) for that.

Comment: I'm still not able to make progress ..1) "travis setup bintray" command in above link doesn't work . 2) Travis descriptor file is not very clear ..